# Spark streaming from Kafka error causing data loss

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming application written in Python that collects data from Kafka and stores it on the file system. When I am running it, I see plenty of "holes" in the collected data. After analyzing the logs, I realized that 285000 out of 302000 jobs failed, all with the same exception:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 604348.0 failed 1 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 4.0 in stage 604348.0 (TID 2097738, localhost): 
kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.handleFetchErr(KafkaRDD.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
```

I know that this exception happens when trying to access a non-existing offset in Kafka. My Kafka topic has 1 hour retention, and I think that somehow my jobs get stuck for more than hour, and after being released the data is no-longer available in the Kafka queue. I couldn't reproduce this issue in small scale, even with very small retention, and I wonder if the jobs can really get stuck and released as I assumed (and how can I avoid it), or I need to look in a completely different direction.

Comment: They don't have to get stuck, they can also just fall behind and not be able to catch up. It seems likely you start from the earliest offset in this scenario. Probably your job fails the first time the cleanup thread on the broker runs. One thought is to make sure you have as many consumer instances in your group as you do partitions to maximize parallelism. If you already have that, consider doing some performance tuning of your application. You can verify by watching if the consumer lag grows out shrinks as your app runs.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Is there a way to verify that the cleanup thread causes the failure and then the lag? Also, will this actually result in "holes" in the data as I described? I would expect more like a delay, and I don't see a delay in real time, only missing blocks...

Comment: If you see lag grow and then suddenly shrink, it is a good indication you've lost some data due to clean up I'd say. The consumer exposes JMX metics you could use to monitor the lag or you could just use the consume group command output to a file repeatedly to monitor this as a time series

Comment: Thing is that I don't see a lag grow and shrink. What I see is that data is suddenly not being written, and when it does again, there is a gap (meaning that I don't see that data that arrived during the stop, and I see the above exceptions in my log).